# finding intersection points in x y data for calculating area of the enclosed area

Tags: matlab

I have x and y data points, after plotting the data, i have this below plot. The data is scattered x y data which contains intersection points. I want to plot these intersection points on the plot like shown below. How do i find these intersection points? i was only able to find functions which compute intersection points for two lines but not scatter data such as this. My main purpose is to separate each box like structure and measure the area using the intersection points, since this method will be automated.

[image]

Comment: If it makes sense for your workflow to find the intersections manually, then you can use `input` with your scatter plot overlaid. In that case, please update your question accordingly to how to record coordinates of manual inputs overlaid to a scatter plot. If you need the intersections programmatically, I am not aware of standard algorithms to do such a thing and a asking for a recommendation beyond standard libraries/functions is off-topic on SO. In that case, you should probably ask more specific questions along how to implement specific interpolation methods you may have in mind.

Comment: As for area, getting (square) area enclosed by (every 4) points is a different question -- on which you can also benefit from asking a more focus question.

Answer (score 0):

If the lines are always going to horizontal and vertical then you could do something like this

```
discriminationCritera = 5 ; % Will need to play with this, how many times more counts does an area need to have to be considered a line
[ N , Xedges , Yedges , binX , binY ] = histcounts2(x,y); % bins the data

% Find number of data points in each row and column
Xsum = sum(N,2);
Ysum = sum(N,1);

% Decided whether it is dense enough to be considered a line
XLines = find( Xsum > discriminationCritera * median(Xsum) );
YLines = find( Ysum > discriminationCritera * median(Ysum) );

% figure out which points are in that bin
xlines = sort(arrayfun(@(line) mean(x( line == binX ) ) , XLines ));
ylines = sort(arrayfun(@(line) mean(y( line == binY ) ) , yLines ));

% Display results
disp(strjoin( ...
[ arrayfun(@(x) sprintf( 'x = %g' , x ), xlines(:) , 'uni', 0)
  arrayfun(@(y) sprintf( 'y = %g' , y ), ylines(:) , 'uni', 0) ] ...
, '\n' ) )

% Calculate areas, flipping is to align with y direction
Areas = flipud( diff( ylines(:) ) ) * diff( xlines(:)' );

% Display more results
disp('Areas enclosed')
disp(Areas)
```

(Sorry for any errors, I don't have a MATLAB license at home and so cannot run the code)